Why are PublicClientApplicationBuilder requires client(app) Secret?
My final goal is manage user's access token by refresh token.
I need token from user.
So, I tried this logic.
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var accounts = app.GetAccountsAsync().Result;
              
 var authResult = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
 .ExecuteAsync().Result;
 var token = authResult.AccessToken

An error occurs in app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes) after logging in with a Microsoft account. When this function is executed, a web browser is launched to prompt for login. After logging in, the browser shows a page indicating that account authentication is complete.
After ms login, this page printed "Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab."
And then, this is error content.

System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
message=One or more errors occurred. (A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: ef0f8da8-2e8b-46ce-8ee5-227b97ea0d01 Correlation ID: e830675e-b28d-48ba-9683-7f4c9bce98c1 Timestamp: 2024-07-10 09:00:43Z)
source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.get_Result()
throw.
1:
MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'. Trace ID: ef0f8da8-2e8b-46ce-8ee5-227b97ea0d01 Correlation ID: e830675e-b28d-48ba-9683-7f4c9bce98c1 Timestamp: 2024-07-10 09:00:43Z

I refer to

https://github.dev/microsoft/semantic-kernel/blob/9dd8604b6868a97ed41b8705bae97b2237ea30b2/dotnet/src/Skills/Skills.OpenAPI/Authentication/InteractiveMsalAuthenticationProvider.cs#L36#L5
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/desktop-mobile/acquiring-tokens-interactively

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
      .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}


Could you include in which platform you added redirect URI and whether you enabled public client flow option or not?

I had a test before using PublicClientApplicationBuilder, which mentioned to enable allow public client flows. Could you please help check it?  In this section, we could see that public client applications can't be trusted to safely keep application secrets, so that it shouldn't require client secret. Therefore, we should enable that option.

I agree with @TinyWang, PublicClientApplicationBuilder does not require client secret. Refer this MS Document.
The error occurs if you missed enabling public client flow option or added redirect URI in platforms other than "Mobile&Desktop application".
I have one app registration where I added redirect URI in Web platform like this:

Initially, I too got same error in console when I ran below code with redirect URL in Web platform:
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

try
{
    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
        .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();
}

var token = authResult.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token}");

Browser authentication:

Error:

To resolve the error, make sure to enable public client flow option and add redirect URI in Mobile and desktop applications platform by removing it from other platforms:

When I ran the code again after making these changes, I got the access token successfully as below:
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    private static string clientId = "appId";
    private static string tenantId = "tenantId";
    private static string redirectUri = "http://localhost";
    private static string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }

        var token = authResult.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token}");
    }
}

Response:

